# show all records in table 1 using many to many relations - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to create a contact report that shows ALL contact persons AND select those who where present.

The presence are stored in a many to many table. Both document id and who was present.

The tables are as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE pe
    (peid int4, peco int4, pename varchar(30));
INSERT INTO pe
    (peid, peco, pename)
VALUES
    (1, 1,'Carl'),
    (2, 1,'John'),
    (3, 1,'Eric'),
    (4, 2,'Donald')
;

CREATE TABLE co
    (coid int, coname varchar(30));
INSERT INTO co
    (coid, coname)
VALUES
    (1,'Volvo'),
    (2,'BMW'),
    (3,'Microsoft'),
    (4,'Apple')
;

There is a also a doc table that is not needed for this query

CREATE TABLE pres 
    (presid int4, presdoc int4, prespe int4);
INSERT INTO pres
    (presid, presdoc, prespe)
VALUES
    (1,1,1),
    (2,2,2),
    (3,2,3),
    (4,3,1)
;
```

The query that do not work (regardless of type of join):

```
SELECT     pename,coname,presdoc AS present 
FROM       pe 
LEFT JOIN  co ON coid=peco
LEFT JOIN  pres ON prespe=peid
WHERE      peco = 1 AND presdoc=2
```

The output of this query is

```
John    Volvo  present
Eric    Volvo  present
```

The desired output is

```
Carl    Volvo
John    Volvo  present
Eric    Volvo  present
```

SQLFiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77b09/21

Thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: First of all +1 for a good question with sample, create statements, fiddle example and showing your effort. Now what is the significance of `presdoc` column and how is it related to other tables?

Comment: And how are you determining if a person was present?

Comment: @utsav The presdoc is related to the actual contact report doc (sqlfiddle). And how are you determining if a person was present? Select this person as present and save this status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you perform like this (if you need simply to check if present)

```
SELECT     pename,coname,presdoc = 2 AS present 
FROM       pe 
LEFT JOIN  co ON coid=peco
LEFT JOIN  pres ON prespe=peid
WHERE      peco = 1
```

Or even better

```
SELECT DISTINCT     pename,coname,presdoc = 2 AS present 
FROM       pe 
LEFT JOIN  co ON coid=peco
LEFT JOIN  pres ON prespe=peid
WHERE      peco = 1
```

Comment: @ Ilya Dyoshin Thank you, but adding more data shows multiple persons http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fb571/2

Comment: Well yes that is how it is intended to work, because you have one-to-one relation between person and company,   and one to many between person and document.

Comment: If I have one contact report I want only the persons present with this document show up. That is the problem.

Comment: then your original query results are OK

Comment: No. I ment not presence from several documents. ALL persons from related company and related presence from ONE document, My original query gave only related presence from ONE document. Persons  without presence was missing.

Comment: then crude force query should be looking like this

SELECT     pename,coname,presdoc AS present 
FROM       pe 
LEFT JOIN  co ON coid=peco
LEFT JOIN  pres ON prespe=peid
WHERE      peco = 1 AND presdoc=2
union select 
pename, coname, null AS present
FROM       pe penull
LEFT JOIN  co ON coid=peco
LEFT JOIN  pres ON prespe=peid
WHERE      
peco = 1 
AND 
presdoc<>2 
AND 
not exists (select 1  FROM       pe pefilter 
LEFT JOIN  co ON coid=peco
LEFT JOIN  pres ON prespe=peid
WHERE      peco = 1 AND presdoc=2 AND pefilter.peid = penull.peid)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with the condition `presdoc=2` which forces to return only records which were present. This is what you need.

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/77b09/28)**</kbd>

```
SELECT pename,
       coname,
       CASE
           WHEN presdoc=2 THEN 'Present'
           ELSE NULL
       END AS Present
FROM pe
LEFT JOIN co ON coid=peco
LEFT JOIN pres ON prespe=peid
WHERE peco = 1
GROUP BY pename,
         coname,
         present
```

Comment: I have been posting at same time

Comment: @Utsav Thank you, but adding more data shows multiple persons: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fb571/1

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have just check wether your document have been issued. then in addition you could create custom aggregate for your boolean check, with logic like "to become and stay true once it reached true":

```
create or replace function max_boolean(agg_state boolean)
returns boolean
immutable
strict
language plpgsql
as $$
begin
  return agg_state;
end;
$$;



create or replace function max_boolean_aggregate(agg_state boolean, el boolean)
returns boolean
immutable
language plpgsql
as $$
begin 
  if (agg_state = true) then
    return true;
  else
      if (el is null) then 
        return false;
      else 
        return el;
      end if; 
  else 
    return el;
  end if;
end;
$$;



create aggregate max_boolean_aggregate (boolean)
(
    sfunc = max_boolean_aggregate,
    stype = boolean,
    finalfunc = max_boolean
);
```

and then your query could be rewritten as following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT     pename,coname,  max_boolean_aggregate(presdoc = 2) AS present 
FROM       pe 
left   JOIN  co ON coid=peco
left   JOIN  pres ON prespe=peid
WHERE      peco = 1 
group by pename, coname
```

and it will be showing wether your person received the document or not.

even more it will be able to support multiple checks :-)

just change the condition inside max_boolean_aggregate()  to presdoc in (2,3)  and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically @Ilya Dyoshin had the solution. I do only put his tiny comment into an answer. First find existing, then UNION non existing. Using NOT IN is simpler than NOT EXIST IMHO.

```
SELECT     pename,coname,presdoc 
FROM       pe 
LEFT JOIN  co ON coid=peco 
LEFT JOIN  pres ON prespe=peid 
WHERE      peco = 1 AND presdoc=2 
UNION
SELECT     pename,coname,NULL AS present FROM pe 
LEFT JOIN  co ON coid=peco
WHERE      peco=1 AND peid NOT IN(SELECT prespe FROM pres WHERE presdoc=2)
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fb571/117

Thanks!

Comment: NOT IN could have some problems with performance on big-huge datasets.  just measure query planner output for big dataset with IN/NOT IN  statements and EXISTS/NOT EXISTS